# Stacked If statements first if condition is always met (menu system)

Tags: c++

I am making a basic vending machine without object orientation and need a menu system for some reason even when i enter 2 into menuChoice the first if condition is met and it prints 2Here's your choco bar sir" when i want a Museli bar!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Choclate=0;
    int Museli=0;
    int CheesePuffs;
    int Apple;
    int Popcorn;
    int menuChoice = 0;
    while (menuChoice != -1)
    {
    cout << "-ENTER CORRESPONDING NUMBER-" << endl;
    cout << "1. Milk Choclate Bar" << endl;
    cout << "2. Museli Bar" << endl;
    cout << "3. Cheese Puffs" << endl;
    cout << "4. Apple" << endl;
    cout << "5. Popcorn" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Choice:  ";
    cin >> menuChoice;
        if (menuChoice = 1)
        {
            Choclate = Choclate + 1;
            cout << "Here's your choco bar sir." << endl;
        }
        else if (menuChoice = 2)
        {
            Museli = Museli + 1;
            cout << "Here's your museli bar sir." << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Heed to your compiler warnings. If your compiler didn't warn you, please consider upgrading it and turning up your Warning levels. .. Its a simple typo `==` instead of `=` in your `if` conditions

Comment: `=` means *assignment*. `==` means *comparison*. They are *not* the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `==`

i.e.

```
if (menuChoice == 1)
```

Better still look up `switch`

Comment: will a case block allow me to keep asking the user for input though?

Comment: he's not telling you to replace whole code with `switch`, just the nested `if`s

Comment: Yes - Better are more readable that writing `if....elseif....else if....`

Comment: Right yeah just stick the switch block in the while loop gotcha

Comment: _"I got you fam"_ Seriously?